# spring boot thymeleaf form-field that is not part of the form-object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working with Spring Thymeleaf just for simple practicing reasons. I have a custom Person-Class for my person schema. This Person-Class does also contain a field for the hashed password.

To add a new Person I have a simple form where the needed attributes for my Person-Class are passed. So I add to the model the following:

```
Person newP = new Person();
model.addAttribute("personForm", newP);
```

And set up the html field like that:

```
   <form action="#" th:action="@{/persons}" th:object="${personForm}" method="post">
```

However I also want to add two extra fields to the form that are not included in the Person-Class:

- Password
- repeat Password

These two fields should be validated after the form has been submitted. Then the password hash field of my Person-Class should be filled with that. This is handled in the function of the corresponding Post-RequestMapping.

Since these two fields are not defined in my person class I wanted to to know if there is still a way to include these two fields into my form without having to add them to my Person-Class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create PersonCreateDto
which include Person entity and another two Felds

```
public class PersonCreateDto{

private Person person;
private String firstfeld;
private String secondfeld;
....
}

PersonCreateDto personCreateDto = new PersonCreateDto();
model.addAttribute("personCreateDto ", personCreateDto );

<form action="#" th:action="@{/persons}" th:object="${personCreateDto}" method="post">
 <input th:type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" th:field="*{personCreateDto.person.firstName}" class="form-control"></input>
 <input th:type="text" name="firstfeld" id="firstfeld" th:field="*{personCreateDto.firstfeld}" class="form-control"></input>
 <input th:type="text" name="secondfeld" id="secondfeld" th:field="*{personCreateDto.secondfeld}" class="form-control"></input>
```